# How to precisely control servo motor by changing duty cycle?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, pwm, servo

I developed a PWM using timer1,using arduino uno and digital output, and identified that when I send a wave with duration of 0.6ms in High level, the motor goes to 0º. If I send 2.1ms, it goes to 180º. I tried to make a relationship between these scales to send the angle and change the time period in order to achieve that angle and it did not work.

I would like to move with a precision of 1 degree, is that possible? Just adjusting the time period.

The model of the motor is mg996r.
Maybe I am missing something.

My code just generates an interrupt over 50 microsencods and I use this to set the frequency of 50Hz and the duty cycle in ms using digitalWrite associated with pin 9.

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

double t = 0.0;

double period = 0;

void setup() 
{
  t = 0;
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);    
  Timer1.initialize(50);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt( timerIsr ); // attach the service routine here
}

void loop()
{
  // Main code loop
  // TODO: Put your regular (non-ISR) logic here
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    float grau = Serial.parseFloat();

    // receive data as angle
    if (grau > 180) grau = 180;
    if (grau < 0) grau = 0;

    // set period for that angle
    // relationship developed between angle and period in ms
    //set it to period
    period = (0.00833*grau + 0.6)*1E-3;  
  }

}

/// --------------------------
/// Custom ISR Timer Routine
/// --------------------------
void timerIsr()
{
    t += 50E-6;
    if (t <= period) {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    }
    else if (t < 20E-3) { // periodo max de 20ms -> 50Hz
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    }
    else {
      t = 0;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I just got it working by creating a timer1 interrupt on CTC mode with a frequency of 100kHz and counting the necessary time to get increments (~ 10us each) of around 1 degree on my servo motor.

More info [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10389/why-timer1-does-not-generate-correct-period-on-ctc-mode-with-a-resolution-of-5us).

Comment: The relationship is like a map between 0.6 ms -> 2.1ms and 0 -> 180 angle degrees. It works, but the problem is that it does not work for a precision of 1 angle degree as Arduino Servo Library does...

Comment: For a precision of one degree, you need a minimum timer increment of 8.33us, which is optimistic. Your current 50us period gives you a resolution of ~6 degrees.

Comment: I tried a resolution of 1us but it didn't work, the motor did not move. Can I achieve this using timer1?

Comment: I found that it has a dead band of 5us. So it won't move until the width changes by 5us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is to use 10us Period, instead of 50us.
 
That precision will be close to 1°

Comment: Thanks, @Mathsman, I got it working, you were right! Just created a timer1 interrupt using CTC mode and then generated an output signal with a frequency of 100kHz that I could increment the angle by approximately 1 degree.

Comment: Your welcome. I recommended this as I have already tried it.

Comment: It has precision of 1.1to 1.2 degrees.